# python data must have variance to compute a kernel density estimate error

Tags: plot

I have a problem with Seaborn and cant make my pairplot correctly. I get error: "distributions.py:306: UserWarning: Dataset has 0 variance; skipping density estimate". I try everything but non of them work. Issue shows when i try to set a 'hue' but before that everything is ok

My dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b81c2.png)

```
Name        OS       Capacity  Ram   Weight  Company      inch
Galaxy S8   Android  64        4     149     Samsung      5.8
Lumia 950   windows  32        3     150     Microsoft    5.2
Xpreia L1   Android  16        2     180     Sony         5.5
iphone 7    ios      128       2     138     Apple        4.7
U Ultra     Android  64        4     170     HTC          5.7
Galaxy S5   Android  16        2     145     Samsung      5.1
iphone 5s   ios      32        1     112     Apple        4
Moto G5     Android  16        3     144.5   Motorola     5
Pixel       Android  128       4     143     Google       5
```

And here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sb
sb.set_style('darkgrid')
smartphones = pd.read_csv('c://smartphones.csv')
sb.pairplot(smartphones, hue='Name', palette='hls', plot_kws={'s':90})
plt.show()
```

As i said without hue every thing is ok:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLoQV.png)

But as i tyr to set hue, i face this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtFB2.png)

Comment: You should present the dataset in the form of characters, not pixels.

Comment: The type of dataset is cvs but i cant attache csv file

Comment: You can't what? You can insert the depicted part of the CSV into the post just as easily as you inserted the code block.

Comment: Aaa... ok buddy god it. I edit my post and insert my dataset. hope it helps. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The warnings occur when diag_kind 'kde' is chosen, which happens automatically with `hue` and the default *diag_kind='auto'*. You can explicitly specify `diag_kind='hist'` or `diag_kind=None`; though there seems to be a bug with the former which makes all histogram bars have the full height.

An alternative which hasn't those issues is

```
sb.PairGrid(smartphones, hue='Name', palette='hls').map(sb.scatterplot)
```

Comment: When I set `diag_kind='hist'` its ok but as you said makes all histogram bars have the full height. but i test 'hue' with another parametrs for example 'Ram' of plot was ok. my code just dont work with 'Name' and 'weight'. So if it didnt work i should forget it and consider another parametrs for hue

Comment: Interesting - 'Name' and 'weight' are the columns with only unique values.

Comment: If I use `hue='Ram'`, I still get `UserWarning`s, and the grid looks different. I added another alternative in the answer.

Comment: Sry i forgot to say that `hue='Ram'` was possible only when i used `diag_kind='hist'` . without that the problem is still exists

Comment: Oh thank you. in alternative way somehow  i have histogram in scatter. now i have another options :D